# Help identify movie with a green lion saving a girl?

Tags: story-identification, movie

One time I randomly clicked a movie and it was obviously a sci-fi/fantasy movie with the best music. It could be late 1970s, but I'm sure it's 1980 and the main thing I can remember is a green lion was the main character. He was saving a girl.
 Can you help me remember the name of this movie?

Comment: Did you watch it on your personal computer? (Since you "clicked") If so, did you check your browser history?  Who knows, it might be as simple as that :)

Comment: If you were so stoned, are you really sure the lion was green?  Or even a lion?

Comment: @JRE, ahah, good point. By the way, if there was indeed a green lion, there is such a thing in Voltron, and there was a Voltron series in the 80's. Don't know about a whole film though. But as you pointed out... The OP's perception of time may have been altered :)

Comment: A green lion? Or [a green tiger](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/heman/images/a/a0/Battlecat_MikeYoung.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090819011540)?

Comment: Why not the old [The Lion, the Witch & the Wardrobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion%2C_the_Witch_and_the_Wardrobe_(1979_film)) cartoon?  Not green, but definitely a lion and the time frame is correct.